# Flutter: Problem with importing a dart file to flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want add a dart file in my flutter project. The dart file has some basic code. I wrote the import statement `import dartfilename.dart` in my main project file. But there is a red line under the `import darfilename.dart`. Could someone please help me? New updates are sometimes very a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:darfilename.dart';
```

Comment: this was not the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you start typing the import statement, your IDE (I'm sure Android Studio does this, but so should VSCode) will suggest files to import. You'll need to point to the correct path of the file. Say your file is in the folder basic_code, you'd do

```dart
import 'basic_code/dart_file.dart';
```

Or if it's a folder up from main, it'd be

```dart
import '../dart_file.dart';
```

If it's in the same folder, you should be able to simply call it directly

```dart
import 'dart_file.dart';
```

So it depends on your file structure. Take a look at this documentation page for more info: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-libraries